# VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting.TestDescriptionAttribute Syntax

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2008, attributes, mstest

What is the syntax to use the [TestDescriptionAttribute][1] of a test to populate the Description column in the Test Results window?

Context:  Visual Studio 2008 Team System

I've read the documentation, but am not able to find a concrete example.

Based, loosely, on Ngu's suggestion, I've tried:

```
using GlobalSim;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting;

namespace GlobalSimTests {

    /// <summary>
    ///This is a test class for PongerTest and is intended
    ///to contain all PongerTest Unit Tests
    ///</summary>
    [TestClass()]
    [TestDescriptionAttribute( "hello" )]
    public class PongerTest {

        private TestContext testContextInstance;

        /// <summary>
        ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
        ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
        ///</summary>
        public TestContext TestContext {
            get {
                return testContextInstance;
            }
            set {
                testContextInstance = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///A test for Ping
        ///</summary>
        [TestMethod()]
        public void PingTest () {
            Ponger target = new Ponger();
            string expected = "Pong";
            string actual;
            actual = target.Ping();
            Assert.AreEqual( expected, actual );
        }

    }
}
```

This compiles, but doesn't display the test description in the Description column of the Test Results window.

[image]

I've also tried this syntax:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///A test for Ping
    ///</summary>
    [TestMethod()]
    [TestDescription( "hello" )]
    public void PingTest () {
        Ponger target = new Ponger();
        string expected = "Pong";
        string actual;
        actual = target.Ping();
        Assert.AreEqual( expected, actual );
    }
```

Which returns from the compiler:

Attribute 'TestDescription' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class' declarations.

Here is the syntax that works.  Thanks all!

```
    /// <summary>
    ///A test for Ping
    ///</summary>
    [TestMethod()]
    [Description( "Hello" )]
    public void PingTest () {
        Ponger target = new Ponger();
        string expected = "Pong";
        string actual;
        actual = target.Ping();
        Assert.AreEqual( expected, actual );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ngu has said, put it on the top of a ***test*** method

```
[TestMethod()]
[Description( "PingTest Check" )]
public void PingTest () {
     Ponger target = new Ponger();
     string expected = "Pong";
     string actual;
     actual = target.Ping();
     Assert.AreEqual( expected, actual );
  }
```

EDIT: [TestDescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.webtesting.testdescriptionattribute.aspx) is from `WebTesting` namespace, which should not be applied for unit testing. Use the [DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.descriptionattribute.aspx) instead, which is part of the `UnitTesting` namespace.

See the modified code above & I am sure, it will work.

EDIT2: To find something like that, look at the classes in the same namespace. That is how classes are arranged, so that one can find it easily.

Comment: That doesn't compile.  Error:  Error 1 GlobalSimTests Attribute 'TestDescription' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class' declarations. C:\Users\Adam\Projects\GGS_Xna\GlobalSimTests\PongerTest.cs

Comment: I am sorry, I should have looked into it in detail. See the modified code and comments above.

Comment: Note: 

[Description( "PingTest Check" )

should be:

[Description( "PingTest Check" )]

Answer (score -1):

```
TestDescriptionAttribute(TestDescription="hi")
```

So for that particular test, the description will be `hi`.

Put it on the top of a method and see whether it works.

Comment: Could you give me a bit more context? I haven't used this before so I'm not sure where to put the code.  Thanks! (Note that I updated the question with the attempt.)